# Bash/Shell Script for automatic backup of website

Tags: php, bash, shell, backup, synology

I'm brand new to shell scripting and have been searching for examples on how to create a backup script for my website but I'm unable find something or at least something I understand.

I have a Synology Diskstation server that I'd like to use to automatically (through its scheduler) take backups of my website.

I currently am doing this via Automator on my Mac in conjunction with the Transmit FTP program, but making this a command line process is where I struggle.

This is what I'm looking to do in a script:

1) Open a URL without a browser (this URL creates a mysql dump of the databases on the server to be downloaded later). example url would be http://mywebsite.com/dump.php

2) Use FTP to download all files from the server.  (Currently Transmit FTP handles this as a sync function and only downloads files where the remote file date is newer than the local file.  It also will remove any local files that don't exist on the remote server).

3) Create a compressed archive of the files from step 2, named as website_CURRENT-DATE

4) Move archive from step 3 to a specific folder and delete any file in this specific folder that's older than 120 Days.

Right now I don't know how to do step 1, or the synchronization in step 2 (I see how I can use wget to download the whole site, but that seems as though it will download everything each time it runs, even if its not been changed).

Steps 3 and 4 are probably easy to find via searching, but I haven't searched for that yet since I can't get past step 1.

Thanks!

Also FYI my web-host doesn't do these types of backups, so that's why I like to do my own.

Comment: Are you looking to just do this with a PHP script? It may be eaiser to do a batch script, or some other scripting language.

Comment: Is the externally hosted website really your master copy? I would think you'd have the master on your own PC or server which you develop on and then push occasionally when you make releasable changes. Then you backup your development system locally.

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks!...so would something like curl --silent http://www.example.com/ do it?

Comment: @mmbratch - it's a site that uses a CMS so I really don't do any development and yeah it's essentially the master because of this.

Comment: @Joey, the Synology NAS is running linux so I assumed I would just write a .sh script

Comment: Do you have `ssh` access? If so, you could largely automate the bulk of this with `rsync`, and the rest is a trivial shell script that uses `tar`, and `find ... +mtime ...-xargs rm` to remove old backups.

Comment: @DopeGhoti yes I have ssh access.  I looked at rsync but it seems overly complicated (at least to me).

Comment: `rsync` is `scp` on steroids; it's exactly the tool for the job you describe and, happily, is not all that much more complex to use than is `scp`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction...I try this out this evening.   In your answer you posted does this all go in a .sh file?  I need to do more reading on rsync, but I thought that didn't run on my synology NAS server (not that it wasn't capable, but that it had to be initiated via SSH from another machine).

Comment: In short, yes, all the components in my answer could easily be more or less dumped into a shell script called as a cron job for daily backups.  I'd suggest running the commands individually to verify that they work, and how they work, and ajust to suit your specific needs.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Thanks again...I'll try them each individually tonight and then start combining them all as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering each of your questions in order, then:

1. Several options, the most common of which would be one of `wget http://mywebsite.com/dump.php` or `curl http://mywebsite.com/dump.php`.
2. Since you have `ssh` access to the server, you can *very* easily use `rsync` to grab a snapshot of the files on-disk with e. g. `rsync -essh --delete --stats -zav username@mywebsite.com:/path/to/files/ /path/to/local/backup`.
3. Once you have the snapshot from `rsync`, you can make a compressed, dated copy with `cd /path/to/local/backup; tar cvf /path/to/archives/website-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tgz *`
4. `find /path/to/archives -mtime +120 -type f -exec rm -f '{}' \;` will remove all backups older than 120 days.

Comment: 1) Used curl...worked fine!
2) Couldn't use rsync because the webhost had that disabled (port denied).  I didn't ask yet if it could be opened, so right now I'm testing the mirroring function of wget...of course it has to download the whole site.

3 and 4 seem easy enough...so I think I'm set.  Many thanks again.  I'll report back in case someone else stumbles on this!

Comment: FYI:  If you can't get `rsync` going, you might could get by with `scp -r`, but that won't show removed files, nor will FTP.

Comment: My Webhost doesn't allow SSH (before when I said I did... I meant to my local synology server). Does this mean I have no options to do an incremental sync/mirror the site locally and remove local files if they are no longer on the host?

Comment: Not outside of taking a complete snapshot and comparing it to the next one.  You could use `rsync` to compare today's to yesterday's locally, perhaps.

Comment: What about lftp using the mirror command with the  - - delete option to remove files not on the remote site?

Comment: Thanks for that, `lftp` is new to me and I'll have to add that to my back pocket.  Good tip!